# deploy maven artifact with multiple profile dependencies

Tags: maven, maven-dependency-plugin, maven-deploy-plugin, maven-profiles

We are relatively new to Maven and now face a problem.

We have a Maven project (projectA) whose JAR is the dependency of several other projects.  Some of the other projects are some custom web container while others are not, so some of projectA's dependency jars are provided in the case of the custom web container, but should be runtime scope in the case of other projects. We currently use exclusion list to filter out the provided jars in the case of the custom web container.

We are wondering if it would be better to use maven profiles.  We know how to create the profiles with different dependencies (actually same dependencies different scope), and in both profiles, the built projectA jar is identical bit-wise.  But what we don't  know is, when we deploy/release the projectA jar artifact to a maven repository, what should the pom.xml look like?  For these web container projects, the pom.xml should not include the provided jars, but for other projects, the pom.xml should include these jars.

We can use a different name for the jar in each profile and deploy each with a different pom.xml, but since these jars are identical bit-wise, it doesn't seem like a perfect solution.  So we thought there's gotta be a better solution to this problem, only that we don't know since we are relatively new to Maven.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The POM is the POM. You seem to be talking about managing transitive dependencies in other projects that reference "A". Your options in Maven are fairly limited:

- You can use exclusions to remove transitive dependencies that you don't want.
- You can declare dependencies in "A" as "provided", but this is only really correct if that jar actually is provided in A's target environment. It's primarily intended for Java EE api dependencies, like servlet-api, which are provided by containers and prohibited from being included in WAR files.
- You can declare dependencies as optional, which is what people usually mean when they say "provided", and manually include those dependencies in the places where they're needed.

I'd personally choose the "optional" route because it's the job of each project to pull in the dependencies it needs, and if something is optional when using "A", it just means things that use "A" have to explicitly choose whether they'll use that optional part of it. This tends to be the best fit when building an artifact that has multiple, differing use cases.

For additional help in this area, you can also use the [maven enforcer plugin](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/maven-enforcer-plugin/) to ban certain dependencies from builds so that you don't accidentally get jars that you don't want.